# Sybase SQL Script for a Report

Tags: sql, join, sybase

I'm trying to put together an SQL script that will give me the following info in one script:
Node, lastUpdatedTime, bytesWritten

From the domain_Client I want to pull out the Node with the latest lastUpdatedTime.

```
From "domain_Client" table:
Node        lastUpdatedTime
Server1     04042015
Server1     04082015
Server2     04072015
Server2     04062015
```

I found a different table with bytesWritten and lastUpdatedTime in domain_JobArchive (instead of the old domain_Jobs which just had bytesWritten).

```
From "domain_JobArchive" table:
bytesWritten    lastUpdatedTime
1000            04042015
2000            04082015
3000            04072015
4000            04062015
```

Desired Result:

```
Node        lastUpdatedTime     bytesWritten
Server1     04082015            2000
Server2     04072015            3000
```

So far I've been able to query the Node and lastUpdatedTime using the following script:

```
select
node, lastUpdatedTime
from domain_Client a
where lastUpdatedTime = (select max(lastUpdatedTime) from domain_Client b
where a.node = b.node
```

I'm stuck on how to include bytesWritten in the script.

I'm a beginner to Sybase SQL so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

So now how do I incorporate bytesWritten into the existing script above?

Comment: Unless your "domain_Jobs" table has more columns, we're stuck too!

Comment: You should have a column - reference key - which can be used to link these two tables. Unless you have it, we cannot link the jobs to corresponding bytes written...

Comment: Saagar, Gerrat, I've added a new table (domain_JobArchive) with lastUpdatedTime that also exists in domain_Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before presenting the solution. I assume that every record in `domain_Client` has an implicit record in `domain_Jobs` on some basis: every time a record is inserted in the `domain_Client` another record is inserted in `domain_Jobs` and the last inserted records appears in the top of the select result , otherwise there is on solution.

I used Oracle because there is no Sybase database support in sqlfiddle.
You can use it as inspiration. Please note that i didn't optimise the queries, so you need to do some tunning.

To be able to do what you want you must have a joining column in `domain_Client` and in `domain_Jobs`. So we will add a new column to the tables ( may be you should create a copies of the tables and do the modification on them).

```
Alter table domain_Client add join_col number;
Alter table domain_Jobs add join_col number;
```

After that create two sequences:

```
Alter table domain_Client add join_col number;
Alter table domain_Jobs add join_col number;
```

update the `join_col` on both table like that:

```
update  domain_Client set join_col = cli_seq.nextval; 
update  domain_Jobs set join_col = cli_jobs.nextval;
```

Now we have we can do a join between the two table and getting your result :

```
SELECT vb.node,
   va.maxupdatetime,
   vb.bytesWritten
FROM
( SELECT node,
         max(LASTUPDATEDTIME) maxupdatetime
 FROM domain_Client
  GROUP BY node) va
INNER JOIN
( SELECT node,
   lastUpdatedTime,
   bytesWritten
 FROM domain_Client a
 INNER JOIN domain_JobArchive b ON a.LASTUPDATEDTIME = b.LASTUPDATEDTIME) vb      ON va.node = vb.node
 AND va.maxupdatetime = vb.lastUpdatedTime
```

Here is the link of the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b504/24)

Comment: thanks for the help. Let me try it out. I've updated my question. Do you mind take a look and offer any suggestion?